# How to return only the first element that matches a criteria in SQL?

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to determine the first time that a new vaccination was given in each country. AKA the first result when these conditions are met for each country, ordered by date

I have this currently:

```
Select dea.location, dea.date, vac.new_vaccinations
From PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths dea
Join  PortfolioProject..CovidVaccinations vac
    on dea.location = vac.location AND
    dea.date = vac.date
where   dea.continent is not null 
    and new_vaccinations is not null
order by date
```

It gives me the number and dates in which each country gave vaccinations, ordered by the date. There are multiple entries for each country though. I tried using Distinct but it didn't work. I would like to know Canada's first date they had a new vaccine, Israel's date when they had their first vaccine, Bahrain's first date when they had a new vaccine etc. Example output Below. Thanks!

```
location    date    new_vaccinations
Canada  2020-12-22 00:00:00.000 5737
Israel  2020-12-22 00:00:00.000 44621
Israel  2020-12-23 00:00:00.000 62838
Canada  2020-12-23 00:00:00.000 8486
Canada  2020-12-24 00:00:00.000 10309
Bahrain 2020-12-24 00:00:00.000 11106
```

Comment: I think we're guessing at the data here. Should we assume that the same date is found in both tables? What if Location XYZ vaccine first date is 2021-01-15, but that particular date is not found in the Deaths table because their data is messy and deaths were not reported that date? Why are you joining on date?

Comment: You probably want to use a full join, instead of inner join, and move your filter predicates to join predicates to account for the possibility of missing days for some countries.

Comment: Im joining on date because that is a column in both tables. Each date will be in both. I am able to get all the dates where new vaccines were given, but I only want the earliest date that each country had an entry into the new vaccinations column. I am a beginner, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"First date" is another way of saying "Min Date" or "Lowest date" so I think you can use an aggregation function:

```
Select
    dea.location,
    min(dea.date) as date,
    vac.new_vaccinations
From 
    PortfolioProject..CovidDeaths dea
    Join  PortfolioProject..CovidVaccinations vac
    on dea.location = vac.location 
    AND dea.date = vac.date
where 
    dea.continent is not null 
    and new_vaccinations is not null
group by 
    dea.location, vac.new_vaccinations
```

Comment: probably want to do a sum new_vaccinations column

Comment: This won't work since you are grouping the rows by `location` and `new_vaccinations` but the second has different values ​​for each `location`

Comment: When I use this function, I still get multiple of each location. Is there any way to order the results and only have 1 entry for each location?

Comment: yes, probably because of the vaccinations, then. You can try summing as suggested by Hogan. Otherwise, you really must provide some sample input and output (you have only shown sample output). It is always a little guesswork otherwise ... for instance I guess that vaccinations wouldn't cause duplicates but I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Joining the two tables on date seems odd, unless you want to display something from the deaths table as well. However, that doesn't seem like the case given your sample output. Also, your question is simply this: `I'm trying to determine the first time that a new vaccination was given in each country`

That could be accomplished with this query:

```
select location, min(some_date) as min_date
from vaccinations
where new_vaccinations is not null
group by location
```

But if you want to also display the number of vaccinations on that date, then additional code is needed. On top of that, you want to exclude locations where the continent is null. Given these requirements, the following query accomplishes all of this:

```
 with first_vaccine as (
    select location, min(some_date) as min_date
    from vaccinations
    where new_vaccinations is not null
    group by location
    )
 select distinct fv.location, fv.min_date, v.new_vaccinations
 from first_vaccine fv
 join deaths d
   on fv.location = d.location
  --and fv.min_date = d.some_date  --this seems unneccessary
 join vaccinations v
   on fv.location = v.location
  and fv.min_date = v.some_date
 where d.continent is not null
 order by location
```

The output is a 3 column output:

```
| location | min_date | new_vaccinations |
```

Which has been represented with data [found in this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g9tMc3zrYgjKCi45HFdvjo/0).